# Find the coefficient of an AR-model

Tags: homework, autoregressive-model

How can I infer the coefficients for an **AR(2)** model given an autocorrelation plot?

What I have tried so far: I can see this a cos-wave of 0.4 Hz, and then i find the values for each step $(1, 0.9211, 0.6967, 0.3624)$. Since it is an **AR(2)** model I have to find to coefficients ($a$ and $b$). Then I can solve two equations with two unknowns. So $a$ is $-0.9991$ and $b$ is $1.8141$. Is that the correct approach? And is it even the correct coefficients?

[image: Rxx]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you know the autocorrelation function, you can use the [Yule-Walker equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model#Yule%E2%80%93Walker_equations) for a generic AR model of order $p$. As you are interested in the case $p=2$, there's no need to complicate things that much.

As stated in [this paper](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Courses/956/ResourceDetails/YWSourceFiles/YW-Eshel.pdf), the equations for the case of an AR(2) are given by:

$$a=\frac{r_1(1-r_2)}{1-r_1^2}$$

$$b=\frac{r_2-r_1^2}{1-r_1^2}$$

where $r_i$ are the coefficients corresponding to the autocorrelation function.